# Is the use of <> as a not-equal operator documented somewhere?

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

looking at existing APEX code I've seen quite a few places where not equal is tested using "<>" instead of "!=". 
I can't find an official documentation where this behaviour is described. Does anyone know if this has any potential side effects? Should that be changed to use != wherever possible?

I'd be thankful for any hints / references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally always use != for clarity, unless I'm looking for a number that is either greater than or less than another number. Since <> implies greater than or less than as opposed to not equals, it doesn't read well with strings - unless alpha-sorting/ranking is what's desired.

For example:

```
String myVar = 'apple';
system.assert(myVar <> 'orange'); // Pass
system.assert(myVar < 'orange'); // Pass
system.assert(myVar > 'orange'); // Fail
```

So in the spirit of creating self-describing code, != is my choice for all "not-equal" scenarios that don't involve ranking or ordering of any kind. Otherwise <> will *work* the same, but with incompatible types you can't perform a < OR a >. In other words:

```
system.assert(myVar <> null); // Pass
system.assert(myVar > null); // Error: Comparison arguments must be compatible types: String, NULL)
```

So whatever more accurately describes the comparison is my 2-cents.

Comment: I agree that != is the better choice and I'd never write <> in an APEX class. I never thought of the <> operator as being a greater than and a less than operator combined.

Unfortunately my original question stays unanswered: Does the use of <> have any potential side effects?

Comment: It seems to work ok in testing but is undocumented. Other languages are the same. You won't find a C++ or Java example of using <> to represent not equal to anywhere. So if a global search & replace isn't possible for some reason and you're stuck with <>, then I'm guessing you're fine leaving the legacy code as is. If anyone answers this question with some definitive "yes" or "no" I'd be very interested in a reference to anything stating as much.

Answer (score 0):

You can find it in formula operators reference [here](http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_functions_a_h.htm&language=en_US#NotEqual)

Comment: Thanks. But that documentation is for formula fields, not exactly what I am looking for.